# ASP.NET MVC Remote Attribute doesn't work in bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have controller with CRUD using Bootstrap modals. I have entity Town and I want to implement that TownName property is unique. So I use Remote attribute:

```
public class Town
{
    ...
    [Required]
    [Remote("IsTownValid", "Town"]         
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In controller I have:

```
public JsonResult IsTownValid(string townName)
{
    return IsTownExist(townName) ? Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet) : Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

private bool IsTownExist(string townName)
{
    // repository-unitOfWork that get town with specified town name
    var town = repository.TownRepository.Get(filter: t => t.TownName == townName).SingleOrDefault();

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(townName))
        return true;
    else if (town != null)
        return true;
    else
        return false; 
}
```

I have Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation library register in _Layout view.

The problem is when I start modal for create town, modal ignore Remote attribute. So, for test purpose I create in that controller standard Create page and Remote validation work perfect. So, my question is why isn't working in modal?

Suggestions, please... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possibly because the modal is being loaded dynamically and you have not reparsed the validator? Side note: Its can be just `Json(!IsTownExist(townName), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: You might also want to look again at the logic in the `IsTownExist()` method. `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(townName)) { return true; }` should be before you database call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen Muecke, thanks for answer because they lead me to answer. This is my JavaScript code that activate modal. I comment the lines that I add to code that activate client-side validation in modal:

```
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {

        $('#m-town-modal-content').load(this.href, function () {
            // this is the first add
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('form'));

            $('#m-town-modal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm(this);
        });       

        return false;
    });
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        // this is the second addition
        if(this.valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {               
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#m-town-modal').modal('hide');                    
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#m-town-modal-content').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }            
    });
}
```